# How can I create a handleOpen function that opens one chakra ui modal, but closes the modal that was previously opened?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chakra-ui

Below is the component that appears when I click on a button, and then there are two new buttons that open a second modal. I need the previous modal to close onOpen of the next modal.

```
function GetFundsDetails({ onClose: onClosePrevious }: Omit<ModalProps, 'children'>) {
  const { isOpen, onClose, onOpen } = useDisclosure();

  function handleOpen(onCloseOriginal: () => void, onOpen: () => void) {
    return () => {
      onCloseOriginal();
      onOpen();
    };
  }

  return (
    <Box>
          <Button onClick={handleOpen(onClosePrevious, onOpen)}>
            Click me to open another modal
          </Button>
          <SecondModalToOpen isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose} />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Thank you for looking into this.

I am trying to pass the first modal `onClose`, into the second modals component, then call that in the `handleOpen` function before returning the `onOpen` for the second modal.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import { useState } from "react";
    import { Box, Button, useDisclosure } from "@chakra-ui/react";
    
    function GetFundsDetails({ onClose: onClosePrevious }) {
      const { isOpen, onClose, onOpen } = useDisclosure();
      const [closePreviousModal, setClosePreviousModal] = useState(onClosePrevious);
    
      function handleOpen(onCloseOriginal, onOpenModal) {
        return () => {
          onCloseOriginal();
          setClosePreviousModal(() => {
            onOpenModal();
            return onClose;
          });
        };
      }
    
      return (
        <Box>
          <Button onClick=handleOpen(closePreviousModal, onOpen)}>
            Click me to open another modal
          </Button>
          <SecondModalToOpen isOpen=isOpen onClose=closePreviousModal />
        </Box>
      );
    }
    
    function SecondModalToOpen({ isOpen, onClose }) {
      return (
        <Modal isOpen=isOpen onClose={onClose}>
          {/* Modal content */}
        </Modal>
      );
}
```

In the GetFundsDetails component, we introduced a state variable closePreviousModal to store the onClose function from the first modal. We also added a setter function setClosePreviousModal to update the value of closePreviousModal.

In the handleOpen function, we update closePreviousModal with the new onClose function from the second modal after closing the first modal. This ensures that the second modal uses the updated onClose function, effectively closing the first modal when the second modal opens.

The SecondModalToOpen component receives the updated onClose function as a prop and uses it to close the first modal when necessary.

Hope above code help you.